# Incrementing decimal numbers in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, numbers

I'm making my way through the beginners tutorials for XNA (C#) and have veered off in my own direction once I learned rendering and positioning, having my own game development experience.

I'm trying to make a property `VelocityY` on my class `Ship`. I want to be able to increment this value by values that are decimal, ie:

```
VelocityY += 0.45;
```

I figured that `float` was the type required here, but when I try compile I get this error:

> Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'float'; use an 'F' suffix to create a literal of this type.

I'm not really sure what the first part means as I haven't made use of `double` as far as I know. `VelocityY` is declared like this:

```
public float VelocityY = 0;
```

I tried using `double` and even `int` instead but I still can't increment by non-whole numbers. Whole numbers work fine.

Comment: Note that C# has a `decimal` type. So, talking about `float` and `double` as being decimal numbers is wrong, since they are stored as binary floating point numbers. Call them floating point numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the literal 0.45 is `double`. If you want to make it a float, use the suffix `f` or `F`, like the compiler error says:

```
VelocityY += 0.45F;
```

Basically, if you don't specify a suffix for a literal including a decimal point, it's implicitly `double`. You can use a suffix to make it explicit:

```
decimal a = 0.45M;
float b = 0.45F;
double c = 0.45D;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the reason that changing the type to `double` doesn't work perhaps because this value is used to increment `Vector2.Position.Y` which I'm assuming is not `double`? If so, this all makes sense.

Comment: yeah, it's should be either all is 'double' or all is 'float'.

Comment: @MartyWallace: Yes, exactly. The result of adding a `double` to a `float` is a double, which can't then be assigned back to the `float` variable.

Answer (score 1):

you should change

```
public float VelocityY = 0;
to
public double VelocityY = 0;
```

or

```
VelocityY += 0.45;
to
VelocityY += 0.45F;
```

Comment: the first must work, unless you defined it in another place. or you missed something. just try now to add to your code the line: 'public double Var = 0.45;' and check it...

Answer (score 0):

By Default all values you give as 0.45 or .68 are double in C# environment, but here you need to say the compiler that the number you gave was float by adding a suffix `F` to it.

variable += 0.45F;